# Socket.io: Wait for animation to complete in client

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I'm doing a turn-based game using NodeJS + Socket.io in the server and ReactJS in the client.

When players perform an action in their turns, it is sent to the server then the server will notify the other players about that action and also start the turn of the next player.

There are some animations when clients receive event from server.

How can I tell the server to wait for all animations in clients to complete before starting the next turn? I know that I can use `setTimeout`, but I think there could be other better approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event listener and then emit to the server once the animation ended.

For example:

```js
const animated = document.querySelector('.animated');

animated.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  console.log('Emit to the server now');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if someone remove the event listener (the code is client-sided so they can easily alter it), the game will freeze because it won't start a new turn unless all animations have completed.

Comment: Anything on the client side can be altered, there's nothing you can do about it.  If you need to secure it, that has to be done on the server side.

The only way to know when an animation ended is in the client. With that being said, you can employ certain strategies to improve the security of the application.

For example, kick user out of the game if they remove the event listener by maintain track of requests and banning 'odd' behaviour, or maintaining a certain amount of times a user can make requests per x seconds, etc. But all these stuff must happen on the server side.

Comment: Yea, so that I don't prefer the client-sided approaches. I think I will let the server tell the clients when to start and when to stop the animations.